# Branch with another GitHub account

Tags: git, github

Every time I committed my code to my repository, my branch show my another account and I don't know how to change that because in my VS Code and in my bash terminal my account is "GustaDNS" and not "Gustavo0DNS"

[image]

I was expecting my username not the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command below, and it will provide you your GitHub username and email that are configured in your local system.

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

Set the appropriate username and email that you want to display in your commit by executing the commands below.

```
git config --global user.name "MYUSERNAME"
git config --global user.email "MYEMAIL@example.com"
```

Comment: `user.name` config has absolutely nothing to do with GitHub username.

Comment: @1615903 `user.name` has everything to do with what name is displayed for commits and branches.

Comment: ...and the name displayed for commits and branches isn't necessarily the *username* used during authentication.